# How do I setup Let's Encrypt tls certificates for Terraform Enterprise?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to setup Let's Encrypt based TLS with Terraform Enterprise. How do I generate the certificate in an acceptable format and inject it into this replicatedctl application?

Answer (score 0):

First, setup your session.

```
alias replicatedctl="/usr/local/bin/replicatedctl"
alias replicated="/usr/local/bin/replicated"
DOMAIN="my.domain.dev"
```

Terraform Enterprise mounts to port 80 as does certbot standalone so we must stop the app in the interim.
Also, it needs to be stopped to update the certificate in TFE.

```
replicatedctl app stop
```

Generate the certificates, follow prompts to run a standalone server to verify the domain if they show up.

```
docker run -it --rm --name certbot -p 80:80 -p 443:443 \
  -v /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt \
  -v /var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt \
  certbot/certbot certonly -v -n -d $DOMAIN
```

Set the certificates in TFE's configuration.

```
replicated console cert set my.domain.dev \
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/privkey.pem \ 
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/$DOMAIN/fullchain.pem
```

Start Terraform Enterprise back up. This will take a few minutes.

```
replicatedctl app start
```